# Vue3 simple store pattern returns empty data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried to follow [this official doc to create a store pattern](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/state-management.html#simple-state-management-from-scratch). However, when running
the code, the data is empty. Surprisingly, when not fully reloading the app, the state gets correct. There is something wrong somewhere.

I made a codebox with all the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-khayyam-xk912?file=/src/App.vue

If you don't want to go to the codebox, here is the code:

##### App.Vue

```js
<template>
  <p v-if="!isFetching">todoLists: {{ todoLists }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./store.js";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      isFetching: true,
      todoLists: store.state.todoLists,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const result = ["cleaning", "working", "singing"];
    store.setTodoLists(result);
    console.log(store.state.todoLists); // This has the expected value
    console.log(this.todoLists);  // This is empty when loading the app the first time, but should not
    this.isFetching = false;
  },
};
</script>
```

##### store.js

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";

export default {
  state: reactive({
    todoLists: []
  }),

  setTodoLists(newValue) {
    console.log(`setTodoLists triggered with ${newValue}`);
    this.state.todoLists = newValue;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data()` is executed before `mounted`. So `todoLists` is **initialized** with the value of `store.state.todoLists` (which is initially empty array) and **never udated again**. You want to move `todoLists` from `data()` into a `computed` (so it can recompute when store changes).

```html
<template>
  <p v-if="!isFetching">todoLists: {{ todoLists }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./store.js";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      isFetching: true,      
    };
  },
  computed: {
    todoLists() {
      return store.state.todoLists
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const result = ["cleaning", "working", "singing"];
    store.setTodoLists(result);
    this.isFetching = false;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I'm still not sure why tutorials (official [and some others](https://michaelnthiessen.com/state-management-without-vuex/)) are using `data()` and not `computed` for their example. Maybe they want to show the simplest way to do it?

Comment: There is subtle but very important difference between the tutorial you linked and your code. They initialize `data()` property with `store.state` which is the `reactive()` object. You are initializing it with the value of the property of reactive object. When the value of the property changes, your data object is not updated because it has no link to `reactive()` object anymore...